# How to access application scope in http session listeners?

Tags: java, servlets

How to get the application scope in the http session listeners in servlets?

Basically I need to remove some values from application scope on automatic session expiry.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Servlet term for “your entire web app at runtime” is *context*.

In the listener, get [servlet context](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) from the [session](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/jms/Session.html) object.
Invoking `session.getServletContext().removeAttribute()` should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context this way:

```
void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se){
 ServletContext context=HttpServlet.getServletContext();
 // Add/delete objects from context
 context.removeAttribute("xyz")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
se.getSession().getServletContext();
```

Comment: If you answer to a question with an already accepted answer, try not to do a bad duplicate of the accepted answer